# Apache http server problems

Tags: apache2, apache

I am using Apache version 2.2.20 (ubuntu) and attempting to use a custom httpd.conf setup however I am getting the following error message and would appreciate any guidance that can be given to me. I'm part of a dev team and was given this custom httpd.conf file so I don't really assume it to be the cause of the problem (but I'm not totally ruling out that possibility).

I run the command "sudo apache2ctl -k restart" and get the following result

```
[Fri Jul 06 11:33:34 2012] [warn] module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping
[Fri Jul 06 11:33:34 2012] [warn] module rewrite_module is already loaded, skipping
httpd not running, trying to start
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action '-k restart' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

The two warnings I can get rid of if I comment out the lines (below) in my httpd.conf file. Do I really want to do this? Where can I go in order to verify that these modules are loaded somewhere else and that commenting them out in my conf file won't hurt anything?

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

As for the error related to not being able to bind to port 80, I cannot get it to go away. When I do a "sudo netstat -lnp | grep :80" I get the following

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80       0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      6233/apache2
```

I know that the above output means that apache thinks its running and for a time I was even able to see the "It Worked!" page when I navigated to localhost, but NOW I only get "Not Found Apache/2.2.20 (ubuntu) server at localhost port 443" when I go to that page. Also I cannot seem to kill the apache process running the "kill -9 6233" command only causes apache's PID to change (for example from 6233 to 6234). I have also tried to use the command "sudo etc/init.d/apache2 stop", it produces an "* Stopping web server apache2                                           [ OK ]" message but again I see the apache2 process taking up port 80.

Ideas on any of these issues would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you might have a different instance of Apache already running.  Try searching from root (/) for 'apache'??

Comment: I restarted the machine and now there is no longer a process running on port 80 (according to "sudo netstat -lnp | grep :80" anyway). However apache won't run. I get the following error "(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action '-k start' failed."

Comment: I hope I'm not confusing the issue here, but I commented out Listen 80 and Listen 443 in my httpd.conf file. I ran the "apache2ctl -k start" command. I got no message of any kind and now I see apache2 running on port 80, however when I navigate to localhost I still reach a "Not Found" page

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look: "module xxx_module **is already loaded**"

Answer: You are loading those modules more than once. Try a search and comment/delete problematic lines:

**In Centos/RHEL:**

```
grep ssl_module -rI /etc/httpd/*   
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
```

In this case ^ I commented out line in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` so all SSL stuff live in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`

Same for `rewrite_module`

```
grep rewrite_module -rI /etc/httpd/*
```

**In Debian/Ubuntu:**

```
grep ssl_module -rI /etc/apache2/*
```

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue where I used SSL keys with passwords. What I did to make it run was:

```
sudo pkill apache2
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

I would not recommend removing `Listen *:80` from your Apache config.