# httpd.conf page (and others) now blank after updating PHP

Tags: php, apache, curl

I am in a beginning PHP/SQL coding class at school. They have us following the Lynda.com videos for help but they don't answer specific questions. I tried to update the PHP per the instructions, then I got this:

Restarting Apache
[Thu Feb 08 21:25:55.945052 2018] [so:warn] [pid 1936] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax OK
Finished.

I tried to go into sudo nano httpd.conf to maybe disable the other version but when I went into that page it was now blank (it was not blank before trying to update PHP). Now my teacher cannot help as he does not work on a MAC and I cannot figure out how to reverse the update so that I can just use what my computer already had. Almost every page I try to go into is blank now.

Please help me, I was just following instructions :(

PS there was this at the beginning of the installation so I'm not sure if it means anything:

MacBook-Pro:Sites Mizgr33n3y3z$ curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.2

---

[WARNING]
Detected macOS High Sierra 10.13. As this is quite new, there may be issues still. Your mileage may vary.

---

Comment: Please format code as code. With Ctrl+K.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache http server problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365630/apache-http-server-problems)

Comment: @waqas per the other page the op stated "The two warnings I can get rid of if I comment out the lines (below) in my httpd.conf file. Do I really want to do this?" - nothing shows when i go to my httpd.conf file so it does not help.

Comment: Looks like you have a LoadModule for PHP7 twice in your httpd.conf (or in some included configuration file.  But this is a warning, it should work anyway.  Create a simple page `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to see what version your are running (or is that blank to?).  A blank page is normally accompanied with a message in the error_log.